# cloud9 ideでサーバーが勝手に落ちる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

cloud9 ide上で

```
 rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

して数時間経つと勝手にサーバープログラムが終了しているのですが、
継続起動する方法は無いでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ウェブIDEを使い続けていてもですか？またアカウントはプレミアム（有料版）でしょうか

Comment: その間、IDEのタブは閉じています。
しかし、しばらくの間はサーバーが動いているようなので
継続起動する方法があるのか気になっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[非アクティブなワークスペース](https://docs.c9.io/docs/inactive-workspaces)の所に無料ユーザーの場合は2時間経つと非アクティブなワークスペースの全てのプロセスが終了されると書かれています。企業が無料でリソースを提供し続けるのは無理なので仕方ない仕様かと思います。
プレミアムであれば、最後に使用した数個（数は支払額次第）のワークスペースに関しては極力終了されないそうですが、それが保証されているわけではなく、メンテナンスの機会などに終了されることもあるとのことです。サーバー機能はあくまでテスト用で一般への配信に使うためではないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: こちらに記載があったのですね！
ありがとうございます。リアルタイムで連絡が取れないメンバーにプロトタイプの動作確認として
使いたかったのですが、プレミアムにするか、あきらめて別の場所へ設置することを検討した方がよさそうですね…。

Comment: とりあえずideが開いていればアクティブっぽいので、メンバーにワークスペースの共有を行えばプロセスを再度実行できるかもしれません。書き込み権限ありならばできそうですが、無しだとちょっとわからないですね